# Html.ActionLink value of ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink, viewbag

In ASP MVC C# I putted a List(Cars) in the ViewBag.cars, now I want to make an actionlink with the title of each car, like this:

```
@if (ViewBag.cars != null)
{
    foreach (var car in ViewBag.cars)
    {
         <h4>@Html.ActionLink(@car.title, "Detail", "Cars", new { id = @car.id }, new { @class = "more markered" })</h4>
    }
}
```

The error I get when I use **@car.title** or just **car.title** as value, I get this error:

```
CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<AutoProject.Models.CarDetails>' has no applicable method named 'ActionLink' but appears to have an extension method by that name.
 Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.
```

What should I fill in as first parameter of the Actionlink?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's because `car` is dynamic, so it doesn't know what the appropriate extension method could be. If you cast `title` to `string`, and `id` to `object`, it'll be fine:

```
<h4>@Html.ActionLink((string) car.title, "Detail", "Cars", new { id = (object) car.id }, new { @class = "more markered" })</h4>
```

Your other option is to make a strongly typed ViewModel.

Answer (score 3):

Try to assign your `car.title` to a variable first then use that variable

```
@if (ViewBag.cars != null)
{
     foreach (var car in ViewBag.cars)
     {
        string title = car.title.ToString();
        <h4>@Html.ActionLink(title, "Detail", "Cars", new { id = @car.id }, new { @class = "more markered" })</h4>
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
foreach (Car car in ViewBag.cars)
    {
    <h4>@Html.ActionLink(car.title, "Detail", "Cars", new { id = car.id }, new { @class = "more markered" })</h4>
}
```

ps I would also make your properties Uppercase rather than lower.

Comment: Try the above instead, sorry missed the foreach out